# Click OK in a Message Box

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel add-in "CData" and if I want to refresh the data a message box pops up for me to click OK or Cancel concerning overwriting the data.  I want to create a macro that I can run that will click OK to the message box so I do not have to do it manually.  I will have this as part of a larger Command Button.
It will not work with Record a Macro under the View ribbon tab.
When recording the macro I hit the keys Alt - S - R - A at this point the message box pops up and ask if I want to continue - with "OK" highlighted.  I hit "Enter" and the file refreshes.  I then hit Alt - W - M - R to stop recording the macro.
This what I get.

```
Sub Macro4()
' Macro4 Macro
    Selection.ClearComments   
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="CDATA0", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "=TrialBalanceReport2022!R1C1:R2C26"
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TABLECDATA0").Resize Range("$A$1:$Z$2")
    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TABLECDATA0").Resize Range("$A$1:$Z$102")
    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TABLECDATA0").Resize Range("$A$1:$Z$1102")
    Cells.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="CDATA0", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "=TrialBalanceReport2022!R1C1:R171C26"
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TABLECDATA0").Resize Range("$A$1:$Z$171")
    Cells.Select
End Sub
```

CDATA0 is the Heading.
TABLECDATA0 is the Data.
TrialBalanceReport2022 is the Worksheet name.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: While not a recommended way of doing things – since it can mess things up if another window is selected or something – you could technically use [SendKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement) to do things like "Hit Enter"

Comment: Can't see anything in the code you posted that's refreshing data or causing a message box.  Have you tried `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`?

Comment: I have added various versions of: Application.DisplayAlerts = False or Application.SendKeys("{Enter}") or Application.SendKeys ("~").  I have put them at the beginning and the end.  I have put those lines just after the Selection.ClearComments line.  I have made sure to have Application.DisplayAlerts = True at the end.  The  code I posted above is not my code it is the code that Excel created from my recording a macro.  I do not know what any of it means.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The "refreshing data" and causing the "message box" comes from the Add-In when I click Refresh All under their CData ribbon item.

Comment: No ideas? Anyone?

Comment: Okay. I figured a way around it.  The problem now is that my VBA turns off Num Lock.

Comment: Private Sub Auto_Open()
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    Application.SendKeys ("%sra")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    Application.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:30"))
    
    'Call OpenGLBalances
    
    
End Sub

Comment: Sorry. I forgot how to make the above comment Code.